# Python - string to matrix representation

Tags: python, string, matrix

1. I have a string `a="1 2 3; 4 5 6"`. How do i express this as a matrix `[1 2 3; 4 5 6]` in Python?
2. I want to then use another such string `b`, convert to a matrix and find `a x b`.

Comment: You should start by trying to code it by yourself and show us some of the ideas you came up with.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`numpy`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html) module to create a matrix directly from a string in matlab type format

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a="1 2 3; 4 5 6"
>>> np.matrix(a)
matrix([[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6]])
```

You can use the same library to do matrix multiplication

```
>>> A = np.matrix("1 2 3; 4 5 6")
>>> B = np.matrix("2 3; 4 5; 6 7")
>>> A * B
matrix([[28, 34],
        [64, 79]])
```

Go read up on the `numpy` library, it is a very powerful module to do all of the type of work that you are referring to.

Answer (score 2):

This is one way to do it, split the string at `;`, then go through each string, split at `' '` and then go through that, convert it to an int and append to a sublist, then append that sublist to another list:

```
a = "1 2 3; 4 5 6"

aSplit = a.split('; ')

l = []

for item in aSplit:
    subl = []
    for num in item.split(' '):
        subl.append(int(num))
    l.append(subl)

print l
```